# Can I monitor which process/user changed file permissions in Python?

Tags: python, logging, audit, file-access

I can get that info via some tool e.g. `loggedfs` or `auditd` etc.

Where do they get it from? Is it possible to check it via Python script without installing 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: Why not call loggedfs or auditd from inside python using os.system or subprocess? That doesn't quite answer the question since it doesn't tell you where the data is, but at least you can check without installing 3rd party libraries.

I should clarify that I don't know loggedfs or auditd, so this may not be helpful.

Comment: Well, `loggedfs` or `auditd` are sort of 3rd party libraries :)

Comment: Haha, I know, it's kind of cheating. It does get the job done though.